# How to make image cover whole Grid?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have project I am working on, and need to set an image as the background on the grid.  I am able to set image, but it does not cover the full width and height of the Grid.

Below is my XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/pt.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

How can I make this cover the full width and height of the Grid?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem.  After a graphic designer designed the image for me, I never bothered to check the size.  It turned out that the Image Width and height was much more than was expected.

After changing the image size to something more appropriate, for example 2560 x 1440, it all seems to be fitting perfectly.

I am not saying this will always be a solution for someone else encountering the same problem I have here, but it is worth checking it out.

Happy coding...

Comment: Note that an image this big might take significant amount of time to load, especially on ARM devices. It might be worth scaling it further down a bit since there are probably less than 0.1% devices capable of this resolution running Windows 8. Perhaps have multiple versions and pick based on screen resolution. Also if you can go even further down - it would be even better. Background images are usually just a background and do not have to be very sharp. Otherwise - you might need to add some more code to either wait for that image to load or fade it in to avoid it just showing up at a point.

Comment: @FilipSkakun Thanks for the meaningfull input.  You mentioned, and I quote, "Perhaps have multiple versions and pick based on screen resolution.", are you referring to having multiple images in different sizes, and pick one based on the screen resolution?  That makes sense, definitely something I will look at. Thanks.